# PDO Pagination - not displaying results

Tags: pdo, pagination

The code is correctly pulling up the number of results in the database, but it's not displaying any results. Instead of displaying results it's displaying the 'else' condition message "No results could be displayed."

I can not figure out what I am doing wrong here... I've looked at a lot of articles and haven't been able to find an answer.

```
<font size="+3" face="Verdana">Database</font>
<br><br>
<form name="form" action="" method="get">
<input type="text" name="q" size="60" />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Search">
</form>

<?php

include 'connect.php';

$var = $_GET['q'];
echo $var;

try {

// Find out how many items are in the table
$total = $conn->query('
SELECT
COUNT(*)
FROM
customers
')->fetchColumn();

// How many items to list per page
$limit = 20;

// How many pages will there be
$pages = ceil($total / $limit);

// What page are we currently on?
$page = min($pages, filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array(
'options' => array(
'default'   => 1,
'min_range' => 1,
),
)));

// Calculate the offset for the query
$offset = ($page - 1)  * $limit;

// Some information to display to the user
$start = $offset + 1;
$end = min(($offset + $limit), $total);

// The "back" link
$prevlink = ($page > 1) ? '<a href="?page=1" title="First page">&laquo;</a> <a 
href="?page=' . ($page - 1) . '" title="Previous page">&lsaquo;</a>' : '<span   
class="disabled">&laquo;</span> <span class="disabled">&lsaquo;</span>';

// The "forward" link
$nextlink = ($page < $pages) ? '<a href="?page=' . ($page + 1) . '" title="Next  
page">&rsaquo;</a> <a href="?page=' . $pages . '" title="Last page">&raquo;</a>' : 
'<span class="disabled">&rsaquo;</span> <span class="disabled">&raquo;</span>';

// Display the paging information
echo '<div id="paging"><p>', $prevlink, ' Page ', $page, ' of ', $pages, ' pages,  
displaying ', $start, '-', $end, ' of ', $total, ' results ', $nextlink, ' </p></div>';

// Prepare the paged query
$stmt = $conn->prepare('
SELECT * FROM customers 
WHERE 
statusstring LIKE :statusstring OR 
company LIKE :company OR 
city LIKE :city OR 
state LIKE :state OR 
zip LIKE :zip OR 
mainphone LIKE :mainphone OR 
contact LIKE :contact OR 
function LIKE :function OR 
cellphone LIKE :cellphone OR 
email LIKE :email OR 
nextcontactdate LIKE :nextcontactdate 
LIMIT :limit 
OFFSET :offset');

// Bind the query params

$stmt->execute(array(':statusstring' => '%'.$_GET['q'].'%',
                 ':company' => '%'.$_GET['q'].'%',
                 ':city' => '%'.$_GET['q'].'%',
                 ':state' => '%'.$_GET['q'].'%',
                 ':zip' => '%'.$_GET['q'].'%',
                 ':mainphone' => '%'.$_GET['q'].'%',
                 ':contact' => '%'.$_GET['q'].'%',
                 ':function' => '%'.$_GET['q'].'%',
                 ':cellphone' => '%'.$_GET['q'].'%',
                 ':email' => '%'.$_GET['q'].'%',
                 ':nextcontactdate' => '%'.$_GET['q'].'%',
                 ':limit' => $limit,
                 ':offset' => $offset));

// Do we have any results?
if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    // Define how we want to fetch the results
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $iterator = new IteratorIterator($stmt);

    // Display the results
    foreach ($iterator as $row) {
        echo "<tr>

  <td align=center>"; if($row['status']==1)
                        {
                        echo "Contacted";
                        }
                      elseif($row['status']==2)
                        {
                        echo "Uncontacted";
                        }
                      elseif($row['status']==3)
                        {
                        echo "Do Not Call";
                        }
                        echo "</td>
  <td align=center>". $row['company'] ."</td>
  <td align=center>". $row['city'] ."</td>
  <td align=center>". $row['state'] ."</td>
  <td align=center>". $row['zip'] . "</td>
  <td align=center>". $row['mainphone'] ."</td>
  <td align=center>". $row['contact'] ."</td>
  <td align=center>". $row['function'] ."</td>
  <td align=center>". $row['cellphone'] ."</td>
  <td align=center>". $row['email'] ."</td>
  <td align=center>". $row['lastcontactdate'] ."</td>
  <td align=center>". $row['nextcontactdate'] ."</td>
  <td align=center valign=middle width=100>
  <form action=customerdetails.php method=POST>
  <input type=hidden value=" . $row['id'] . " name=id>
  <input type=image src=images/details.png height=30>
  </form>
  </td></tr>";
    }

} else {
    echo '<p>No results could be displayed.</p>';
}

} catch (Exception $e) {
echo '<p>', $e->getMessage(), '</p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: You need to debug your code. Tweak and run it using your computer and see what happens. It's 1000 times more efficient than just looking into code and trying to run it mentally.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864034/why-might-this-work-on-my-server-but-not-my-schools

Comment: I have figured out a little bit of it. Got it to display results... now just need to fix the pagination part. The duplicate you linked has nothing to do with my topic? Assuming that's an accident.